# Backbone.js Collection not iterating

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
PaperSection = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    title: '',
    position: ''
  },

  initialize: function(){

  },

  renderView: function(){
    return "<li>"+this.get('title')+", Position: "+this.get('position')+"</li>"
  }
});


PaperSectionsList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/admin/paper/section/list.html',
  size: 6,
  initialize: function(){
    this.add(new PaperSection({
      id:1,
      title: "Hello World",
      position:1
    }));
  },

  comparator: function(section){
    return section.get('position');
  },

  renderView: function(){
    var html = "<ul>";
    _.each(this.models, function(section){
      html += section.renderView();
    });
    if(_.size(this.models) < this.size){
      html+="<li><a href='#add_section' class='btn btn-success btn-small' id='add_section'>Add Section</a></li>"
    }
    html+="</ul>";
    return html;
  }
});

PaperSectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.render();
  },

  render: function(){
    console.log(this.collection.get(1));
    var html = this.collection.renderView();
    this.$el.html(html);
  }
});

var paper_sections = new PaperSectionsList({
      model: PaperSection,
    });
    var section_view = new PaperSectionView({
      collection: paper_sections,
      el: $('#paper_sections')
    });
```

When I run the code I get the error that `section.renderView()` is not a function. Need help with this. How do I iterate over models in my collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are defining your collection and instantiating it incorrectly.

The `model` declaration needs to happen in the collection's definition, not in the instantiation:

```
PaperSectionsList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: PaperSection,
```

And then you just instantiate it:

```
var paper_sections = new PaperSectionsList();
```

That will get your code working.

But, I feel compelled to point out that you have some confusion about your coding concerns.  `Models` and `Collections` should never have functions called `render*`.  These are `View` concerns.  In your case, the idiomatic way of handling it would be to have to views: `PaperSectionListView` (`ul`) and `PaperSectionListItem` (`li`).  The templates and render functions live in those views.

Answer (score 0):

I've got your code working as follows...

But I think the above answer handles the core issue, and I agree with the suggestions that the Models and Collections should not be handling render logic.

Note: I cleaned up some JSLint errors such as and extra comma and missing semicolons.

```
var PaperSection = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title: '',
        position: ''
    },

    initialize: function () {

    },

    renderView: function () {
        return "<li>" + this.get('title') + ", Position: " + this.get('position') + "</li>";
    }
});


var PaperSectionsList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/admin/paper/section/list.html',
    model: PaperSection,
    size: 6,
    initialize: function () {
        this.add(new PaperSection({
            id: 1,
            title: "Hello World",
            position: 1
        }));
    },

    comparator: function (section) {
        return section.get('position');
    },

    renderView: function () {
        var html = "<ul>";
        _.each(this.models, function (section) {
            html += section.renderView();
        });
        if (_.size(this.models) < this.size) {
            html += "<li><a href='#add_section' class='btn btn-success btn-small' id='add_section'>Add Section</a></li>";
        }
        html += "</ul>";
        return html;
    }
});

var PaperSectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
        console.log(this.collection.get(1));
        var html = this.collection.renderView();
        this.$el.html(html);
    }
});

$(function () {

    var paper_sections = new PaperSectionsList({
        model: PaperSection
    });

    var section_view = new PaperSectionView({
        collection: paper_sections,
        el: $('#paper_sections')
    });

});
```